# Swift4 空配列の特性について

Tags: swift, swift4, array

配列を用いてタスク管理を行おうと思いました。

```
var foo:Array = [String]()
//要素を最後尾に追加
func add(value:String){
    foo.append(value)
}
// valueを配列内から検索し、削除
func remove(value:String){
    foo.remove(at: foo.indexOf(value))
}

add(value:"bar")
remove(value:"bar")
```

そこでタスクを入れておく空の配列を用意し、そちらに要素を追加、
そして削除までの流れを行いたいのですが、

```
error: TestArea.playground:2:20: error: value of type 'Array<String>' has no member 'indexOf'
    foo.remove(at: foo.indexOf(value))
                   ^~~ ~~~~~~~
```

このようなエラーが出てしまい、追加の段階まで処理が進みません。
デフォルトで何らかの値を入れておけば問題なく動くのですが、それでは意味がないので、何かしらの策はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... has no member 'indexOf'
```

^ 上記のメッセージは配列の要素がないという意味ではありません。
「`indexOf`というメソッド」が`Array<String>`に見つからないという意味です。

`indexOf(:_)`というメソッドは古いSwift 2のときの書き方で、現在、同等のメソッドは`index(of:)`になります。

よってこの意図した挙動のコードは例えば下記のようになります。

```
func remove(value: String){
    if let index = foo.index(of: value) {
        foo.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Comment: 参考になりました。ありがとうございます。
Swiftのドキュメントはどうしてもバージョンによる変化の対応が厳しいので、しっかり確認する必要があるなと感じました。